# Object fields still faulted after save and re-access (MagicalRecord)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I use [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) in my application.

I have a property called `contactDetails` in my ViewController.
This is an NSManagedObject subclass.

The ViewController allows me to make changes to this object (i.e. change its properties).
When I am done, I save it using:

```
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // saving complete
    }];
```

Now, if I were to make any more changes to `contactDetails`, followed by another save, my app crashes. (SIGABRT)

It turns out that `contactDetails` now is faulted.

Why is `contactDetails` faulted after it has been saved?

How can I keep make changes to the object after the first save and still be able to save it again later?

**p.s.**

I have tried accessing individual properties of `contactDetails` after this but they are all nil or NULL. i.e. accessing the `contactDetails` properties does not load the object correctly.

Comment: There is not enough context in your question. There is nothing MagicalRecord is doing to fault or reset the defaultContext. Are you only using the default context?

Comment: Yes exactly. Once i save using the default context in the above manner, the objects properties are fault and cannot be accessed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `contactDetails` object was passed between viewcontrollers which both had this object as a property. The first view controller accidentally released the property and so the property in that second viewcontroller became **fault**.